# Tkinter panedwindow not opening

Tags: python, widget, tkinter

I have created a panedwindow in python tkinter with two panes. It will open fine on it's own but within an if statement it no longer opens

First I had just the code for the panedwindow on it's own but I wanted to use it within another section of code. It won't work within an if statement, it appears to be ignored. Where have I gone wrong?

```
from tkinter import *
import time

ticketCost=6
username="Rob"

code = input("Enter code: ")
if code == "123":
    year=str(time.localtime()[0])
    month=str(time.localtime()[1])
    day=str(time.localtime()[2])
    hour=str(time.localtime()[3])
    minute=str(time.localtime()[4])
    ticketTime=str(hour+":"+minute)
    ticketDate=str(day+"/"+month+"/"+year)
    ticketInfo="Bus ticket\nSingle\nDate: "+ticketDate+"\nTime: "+ticketTime+"\nPassengers: "+
    ...str(int(ticketCost/3))+"\nPrice: "+str(ticketCost)+" credits"
    ticketWindow = PanedWindow(orient=VERTICAL,bg="white")
    ticketWindow.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    top = Label(ticketWindow, text="top pane")
    photo = PhotoImage(file='Coach 1.gif')
    top.config(image=photo,bg="white")
    top.image = photo
    ticketWindow.add(top)
    bottom = Label(ticketWindow, text="bottom pane")
    bottom.config(text=ticketInfo)
    bottom.config(bg="white")
    ticketWindow.add(bottom)
    print("\nThank you", username)
else:
    print("no")
```

Comment: FWIW - `year,month,day,hour,minute = map(str,time.localtime()[:5])` I think should work

Comment: my problem is the panedwindow does not open

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't saying that would cause your program to work.  Just clean things up a bit.  I'm assuming that you're sure that you're taking the right branch in the `if` statement and things still don't show up?

Comment: Are you certain the code ibside the 'if' is being executed?

Comment: ok now thanks to the tidy up the panedwindow is opening, how do I get it to appear on top/getfocus

Answer (score 0):

You do not appear to be making a root window, and are not starting the event loop.

Comment: I am very new to python, what does this mean?

Comment: It means you must first create an instance of the class `Tk`, and then you must call the `mainloop` method of that instance as the last line of your program. For example: http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/hello-tkinter.htm